# How to reverse urls with DjangoCMS 2.4.x and apphooks

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-cms

I am using Django CMS django-cms==2.4.3

I have prepared an apphook, called Products.

My cms_app.py file is:

```
class ProductsApp(CMSApp):
    name = _("Products")
    urls = ["products.urls"]

apphook_pool.register(ProductsApp)
```

My models.py file is:

```
class Region(TranslatableModel):
    slug = models.SlugField(_('short name for URL'))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('products_region', args=(self.slug, ))
```

My urls.py files is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'products.views',
    url(r'region/(?P<slug>.*)/$', 'region', name='products_region'),
)
```

In my template I am refering to the url as:

```
<li><a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
```

My question is: am I doing right?
Sometimes it is working, sometimes I receive a lot of errors like this:

```
Reverse for 'products_region' with arguments '(u'veneto',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

How can I make it work? Is this a django-cms bug? Thank you

Comment: make sure to add the apphook to all the languages being used in the page and to restart the server afterwards.

Comment: So, the correct procedure is:
- add the apphook to every translation of the page
- restart the server

Comment: Yes, on cms >= 3, we've removed the language specific apphooks, so you only add the apphook once but < 3, you need to add it to all translations.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to restart the webserver after you have added the apphook.

Comment: I have restarted (ctrl+c and then restart), but it is not working. I am developing with the ./manage.py runserver server, but the same happens with Apache and mod_wsgi.